# Mass conversion of .JP2 images to .TIF format in R

Tags: raster, r, convert, rgdal

I need to convert a list of .jp2 files to .tif. I cannot do it manually since it is a large number of files. So I can't use:

```
gdal_translate(path_vhr_imag_1, "splt1.tif")
gdal_translate(path_vhr_imag_2, "splt2.tif")
```

I have found this code to convert a list of .jp2 files but it is not working properly. 
Source: https://geoinnova.org/blog-territorio/sig-conversion-masiva-de-imagenes-sentinel-2a/

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(tools)

setwd("D:/list_test")

#Nombre de la carpeta de destino de los ficheros tif
carpetaTif <- 'tif/'

#Lista con los ficheros originales en formato jp2
lista.jp2 <- list.files('D:/list_test',pattern='.jp2',full.names=TRUE)

#Bucle para recorrer la lista de ficheros jp2 que queremos convertir
for(jp2 in lista.jp2){
  r <- raster(readGDAL(i))
  outRaster <- file_path_sans_ext(basename(i))
  writeRaster(paste(carpetaTif,outRaster,'.tif',sep=''),r,overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Error:
**Error in readGDAL(i) : object 'i' not found**

Can anyone find the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have `i` defined in the for loop. Currently the iterator is defined as `jp2` just change to `for(i in lista.jp2)`

Also, for naming your output raster using `writeRaster` take a look at `file.path` rather than `paste` or `paste0`. For example: `file.path(getwd(), "tif", file_path_sans_ext(basename(i)),".tif")` would return something like: "D:/list_test/tif/theraster.tif"

You can omit the spurious objects by nesting functions and subset the file name without an additional package. File names can be extracted using: `sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", basename(i))` However, it is not entirely necessary to pull the file names becaues you can just use `gsub` to replace jp2 with tif resulting in a vector of the new file names.

```
setwd(...)
in.files <- list.files(getwd(),"jp2$")
out.files <- gsub(".jp2", ".tif", in.files)
  for(i in 1:length(in.files)){
    raster::writeRaster(raster(rgdal::readGDAL(in.files[i])),
                        file.path(getwd(), "tif", out.files[i]),
                        overwrite = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: Great. I really appreciate your answer.
It is really interesting to use the `gsub` function to create the names of the output files.It works perfectly for .jp2 files with a single band (Ex: Sentinel-2). What modifications would I need for a .jp2 file type raster stack or raster brick (with 4 bands for example)?